# Rust compiler infers Least Upper Bound type of first match pattern regardless if it matches

Tags: rust

**Context**: our program is reading events from multiple Kafka topics and proceeds to persist them to an upstream datastore. To make the API more ergonomic we operate over generic types that are bounded by key traits.

**Problem**: when reading a message from a channel we have a tuple containing the `topic`, `event_id` and the generic `event`. Depending on the value of the `topic` we want to do treat the `event` as a different concrete type. The compiler however always coerces the generic `event` type to the first pattern, regardless if it matches that arm or not.

```rust
Some(message) = rx.recv() => {
    match message {
        Ok((topic, event_id, event)) if topic == "my.first.topic" => {
            write_messages::<database::FirstEventType, protobuf::FirstEventType>(...).await;
        },
        Ok((topic, event_id, event)) if topic == "my.second.topic" => {
            write_messages::<database::SecondEventType, protobuf::SecondEventType>(...).await;
        },
        Ok((topic, _, _)) => {
            tracing::error!("received message from an unknown topic: {topic}");
        }
        Err(e) => {
            tracing::error!("received error from message handler: {e:?}");
        }
    }
},
```

The second branch however causes a compiler error as it infers `event` to be `protobuf::FirstEventType` rather than `protobuf::SecondEventType` despite matching on the second arm.

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> sink/src/main.rs:68:67
   |
68 | ...buf.push((topic, event_id, event));
   |                               ^^^^^ expected struct `SecondEventType`, found struct `FirstEventType`
   |
   = note: expected struct `SecondEventType`
              found struct `FirstEventType
```

After some reading, it *appears* to be related [Least Upper Bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#least-upper-bound-coercions) type coercion which selects the first concrete type in the match arm.

**Question:** is there a neat way to signal to the compiler that the concrete type will vary depending on each match arm?

Comment: Sounds like SecondEventType is not related to FirstEventType at all? Match arms can't have different types like that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev they are, in that the underlying channel returns `(String, Uuid, T)` where `T` implements a particular Trait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to get away with trait objects.
Before you push the tuple try to casting it to a tuple containing a trait object.

```rust
//your sink/src/main.rs:68
buf.push((topic, event_id, Box::new(event) as Box<dyn TheTrait>))
```

but this will only work if the trait returned is [object safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety).

---

If it is not object safe you'd have to wrap it in an enum and match on that:

```rust
enum EventType {
    First(protobuf::FirstEventType),
    Second(protobuf::SecondEventType),
    // further variants
}
impl From<protobuf::FirstEventType> for EventType {
    fn from(val: protobuf::FirstEventType) -> Self {
        EventType::First(val)
    }
}
impl From<protobuf::SecondEventType> for EventType {
    fn from(val: protobuf::SecondEventType) -> Self {
        EventType::Second(val)
    }
}
// further impl From<T>
// sink/src/main.rs:68
buf.push((topic, event_id, EventType::from(event)));
```

and match on the enum:

```rust
Some(message) = rx.recv() => {
    match message {
        Ok((topic, event_id, EventType::First(event))) if topic == "my.first.topic" => {
            write_messages::<database::FirstEventType, protobuf::FirstEventType>(...).await;
        },
        Ok((topic, event_id, EventType::Second(event))) if topic == "my.second.topic" => {
            write_messages::<database::SecondEventType, protobuf::SecondEventType>(...).await;
        },
        …
    }
}
```

Comment: I've gone ahead with an implementation very similar to the second. It adds a bit of additional reasoning but overall feels like less of a hack and is closest to what I was looking for. Thank you @cafce25!